# Get list of dates based on condition XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, text, xslt-2.0

I have this scenario wherein:

1. if `wd:F03_First_Start` is equal to 0 and `wd:F03_Last_Day` is less than or equal to `wd:End_Date`, get the dates from `wd:First_Day` to `wd:F03_Last_Day`
2. if `wd:F03_First_Start` is equal to 0 and `wd:F03_Last_Day` is greater than `wd:End_Date`, get the dates from `wd:First_Day` to `wd:End_Date`
3. if `wd:F03_First_Start` is equal to 1 and `wd:F03_Last_Day` is less than or equal to `wd:End_Date`, get the dates from `wd:Start_Date` to `wd:F03_Last_Day`
4. if `wd:F03_First_Start` is equal to 1 and `wd:F03_Last_Day` is greater than `wd:End_Date`, get the dates from `wd:Start_Date` to `wd:End_Date`

Also, each date needs to get another value depending on what day they are. If it's 09-11-2018 (dd-MM-yyyy) which is Friday (vendredi in  French), it should get the value from `wd:F01_vendredi`.

For reference:
lundi (Monday)
mardi (Tuesday)
mercredi (Wednesday)
jeudi (Thursday)
vendredi (Friday)
samedi (Saturday)
dimanche (Sunday)

Here is the XML:

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.report/F03">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:ID>00000001</wd:ID>
        <wd:LOA>
            <wd:Type>XYZ</wd:Type>
            <wd:First_Day>09-11-2018</wd:First_Day>
            <wd:F03_First_Day>vendredi</wd:F03_First_Day>
            <wd:F03_Last_Day>12-11-2018</wd:F03_Last_Day>
            <wd:F03_Last>lundi</wd:F03_Last>
            <wd:F03_First_Start>0</wd:F03_First_Start>
        </wd:LOA>
        <wd:F01_lundi>1</wd:F01_lundi>
        <wd:F01_mardi>2</wd:F01_mardi>
        <wd:F01_mercredi>3</wd:F01_mercredi>
        <wd:F01_jeudi>4</wd:F01_jeudi>
        <wd:F01_vendredi>5</wd:F01_vendredi>
        <wd:F01_samedi>6</wd:F01_samedi>
        <wd:F01_dimanche>7</wd:F01_dimanche>
        <wd:Start_Date>01-11-2018</wd:Start_Date>
        <wd:F03_Start_Day>jeudi</wd:F03_Start_Day>
        <wd:End_Date>30-11-2018</wd:End_Date>
        <wd:F03_End_Day>vendredi</wd:F03_End_Day>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:ID>00000002</wd:ID>
        <wd:LOA>
            <wd:Type>ABC</wd:Type>
            <wd:First_Day>25-06-2018</wd:First_Day>
            <wd:F03_First_Day>lundi</wd:F03_First_Day>
            <wd:F03_Last_Day>03-12-2018</wd:F03_Last_Day>
            <wd:F03_Last>lundi</wd:F03_Last>
            <wd:F03_First_Start>1</wd:F03_First_Start>
        </wd:LOA>
        <wd:F01_lundi>6</wd:F01_lundi>
        <wd:F01_mardi>5</wd:F01_mardi>
        <wd:F01_mercredi>4</wd:F01_mercredi>
        <wd:F01_jeudi>3</wd:F01_jeudi>
        <wd:F01_vendredi>2</wd:F01_vendredi>
        <wd:F01_samedi>1</wd:F01_samedi>
        <wd:F01_dimanche>0</wd:F01_dimanche>
        <wd:Start_Date>01-11-2018</wd:Start_Date>
        <wd:F03_Start_Day>jeudi</wd:F03_Start_Day>
        <wd:End_Date>30-11-2018</wd:End_Date>
        <wd:F03_End_Day>vendredi</wd:F03_End_Day>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

My desired output is:

```
00000001;09-11-2018;XYZ;5
00000001;10-11-2018;XYZ;6
00000001;11-11-2018;XYZ;7
00000001;12-11-2018;XYZ;1
00000002;01-11-2018;ABC;3
00000002;02-11-2018;ABC;2
...
...
...
00000002;30-11-2018;ABC;2
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function to create an XSLT/XPath `xs:date` from your date format, then you can set up templates for your conditions and process the dates, here is an example for the first of your conditions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.report/F03"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="month-names" as="xs:string+"
        select="'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi', 'dimanche'"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:createDate" as="xs:date">
        <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(replace($date, '([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})', '$3-$2-$1'))"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry[LOA/F03_First_Start = 0 and mf:createDate(LOA/F03_Last_Day) le mf:createDate(End_Date)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="date">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="mf:createDate(LOA/First_Day)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="last-date" select="mf:createDate(LOA/F03_Last_Day)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry" mode="date">
        <xsl:param name="date"/>
        <xsl:param name="last-date"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ID, format-date($date, '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]'), LOA/Type, *[local-name() = 'F01_' || lower-case(format-date($date, '[F]', 'fr', 'AD', 'FR'))]" separator=";"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="next-date" select="($date + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))[. le $last-date]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".[exists($next-date)]" mode="date">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$next-date"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="last-date" select="$last-date"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this requires an XSLT 3 processor like Saxon PE or EE to support the extraction of the `fr` french week day name directly from the `xs:date` using the `format-date` function with e.g. '[F]', 'fr', unfortunately the HE version of Saxon does not support that, there you get the English name or the English week day number so for HE you could try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="urn:com.report/F03"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="month-names" as="xs:string+"
        select="'lundi', 'mardi', 'mercredi', 'jeudi', 'vendredi', 'samedi', 'dimanche'"/>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:createDate" as="xs:date">
        <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(replace($date, '([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})', '$3-$2-$1'))"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry[LOA/F03_First_Start = 0 and mf:createDate(LOA/F03_Last_Day) le mf:createDate(End_Date)]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="date">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="mf:createDate(LOA/First_Day)"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="last-date" select="mf:createDate(LOA/F03_Last_Day)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Report_Entry" mode="date">
        <xsl:param name="date"/>
        <xsl:param name="last-date"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="ID, format-date($date, '[D01]-[M01]-[Y0001]'), LOA/Type, *[local-name() = 'F01_' || $month-names[xs:integer(format-date($date, '[F1]', 'en', (), ()))]]" separator=";"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="next-date" select="($date + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D'))[. le $last-date]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".[exists($next-date)]" mode="date">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="$next-date"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="last-date" select="$last-date"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nc4NzRr/1. For XSLT 2 you could need to replace the use of the `||` string concatenation operator with calls to the `concat` function: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/nc4NzPV.